# Sync Calendar Events to google account

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, synchronization

The users of my app are able to create events for native calendar app on their phone through my app. i have done this with the following code :

```
    long startMillis = 0;
    long endMillis = 0;
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2014, 1, 14, 17, 00);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2014, 1, 14, 17, 30);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
    eventValues.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    eventValues.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    eventValues.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault()
            .getDisplayName());
    eventValues.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 7);
    eventValues.put(Events.TITLE, title);
    eventValues.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    eventValues.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
    eventValues.put(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_DEFAULT);
            Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventValues);
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

With the above code i was able to successfully add an event in the native calendar app on the phone/tablet. But that event was not reflecting in the calendar app of his gmail account even though i have manually synced the corresponding account in phone's settings. Whereas if i add an event using the native calendar app on the phone/tablet, that corresponding event is being reflected in the calendar app of his gmail account.

i have tried to read the source code for calendar app from here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git

but as far as i could understand, they have also done it the same way in the calendar app at least. i have read similar questions on the same topic, but no one gave an correct answer or even mentioned alternative methods (other than android api's)

So, Can anyone please tell me on how to sync the calendar events that are created through my app to their corresponding gmail account. is there any way to get it done atleast by using google calendar apis  for android ??? is there such an api ???

Comment: Got any clue for your issue. I am facing same issue, but not able to replicate it.